# How to find all multi-directional relations between two nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find all relations between node a and node b, and the relations could be multi-directions. For example,
a <- c -> b or a -> d -> b where c and d are nodes.

I've tried `MATCH (a:PERSON {name: 'WD'})-[r*..3]-(b:PERSON{name: 'EK'}) RETURN r, a, b`, but I got two isolated nodes, because the relation between a and b is: a <- c -> b.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "isolated nodes"? The `r` you should have gotten would have been a *list* of relationships (since you used a variable-length relationship pattern).

Comment: @cybersam "Isolated nodes" means I only get two nodes without any connection. Anyway, thank you for your help! I have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the **path** if you need all the relationships and nodes in between.

Following query will
You can modify your query to return full paths instead of just nodes `a` and `b` as following:

```
MATCH paths=(a:PERSON {name: 'WD'})-[r*..3]-(b:PERSON{name: 'EK'})
RETURN paths
```

**This will return paths of length up to 3, change it as you need.**

Comment: Thank you @Raj ! It works! I thought paths must be in one direction.

Comment: It can be both directions unless you specify the direction